# Definition of strategy in extensive form games

Tags: game-theory

> **Definition 3.9** A strategy for player i is a function s<sub>i</sub> mapping each vertex x ∈ V<sub>i</sub> to an element in Action(x)(equivalently, to
> an element in Child(x)). V<sub>i</sub> is the set of *all* vertices in
> game tree where player i makes a move.
>
> *According to this definition, a strategy includes instructions on how to behave at each vertex in the game tree, including vertices that
> previous actions by the player preclude from being reached. For
> example, in the game of chess, even if White’s strategy calls for
> opening by moving a pawn from c2 to c3, the strategy must include
> instructions on how White should play in his second move if in his
> first move he instead moved a pawn from c2 to c4, and Black then took
> his action. The main reason this definition is used is its simplicity:
> it does not require us to provide details regarding which vertices
> need to be dealt with in the strategy and which can be ignored.*
>
> **Definition 3.10** A strategy vector is a list of strategies s = (s<sub>i</sub> )<sub>i ∈N</sub> , one for each player.
>
> Player i’s set of strategies is denoted by S<sub>i</sub>, and the set
> of all strategy vectors is denoted
> S=S<sub>1</sub>×S<sub>2</sub>×...S<sub>n</sub>. Every strategy vector
> s=(s<sub>i</sub>)<sub>i ∈N</sub> determines a unique play(path from
> the root to a leaf). The play that is determined by a strategy vector
> s = (si)<sub>i ∈N</sub> is (x0,x1,x2,...,xk), where x1 is the choice
> of player at vertex(x0), based on his strategy, x2 is the choice of
> player at vertex (x1) based on his strategy, and so on, and xk is a
> leaf. The play corresponds to the terminal point xk (with outcome
> u(xk)), which we also denote by u(s). (u denotes outcome of game - at leaf.)

Now,  A strategy s<sub>I</sub> of Player I is called a winning strategy if
u(s<sub>I</sub>, s<sub>II</sub>) = I wins, ∀s<sub>II</sub> ∈ S<sub>II</sub>.

I'm confused as to why  ∀s<sub>II</sub> ∈ S<sub>II</sub> has been written. By definition, s<sub>II</sub> is a function which maps all possible vertices to their next move, so why is there a set S<sub>II</sub>? Under 3.10, what is meant by player i's *set of strategies*?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: "Player $i$’s set of strategies is denoted by $S_i$". The set $S_{II}$ is the set of all strategies of player $II$ (seriously - Roman numerals?). The definition is just saying that $s_I$ is a winning strategy for player 1 if it beats *every* strategy that player 2 has.